# If $value is truthy, return $value, else return something else

Tags: php

I know you can to this

```
$var = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM..") ? mysql_query("SELECT * FROM.."):'Nope!';

// the same as this

if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM..")) $var = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM..");
else $var = 'Nope!';
```

But it's inconvenient, because what if it was a function that either returned an array or false and maybe updated some data in a table. So I wondered if there is any way to do

```
$var = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM..") ? $returnOfFunction:'Nope!';
```

Something like this

```
$var = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM..") || 'Nope!';
```

But in php, that means if this is true or this is true, then i am true

I hope someone can understand my thoughts.

EDIT:
Would this work?

```
function pickTrue($one, $two) {
  if($one == true) return $one;
  else return $two;
}

$var = pickTrue(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"), 'Nope');
```

Comment: Focus on making your code readable

Comment: To put John's suggestion in other words, this type of tricks are going to do nothing except make your code hard to understand. `if`/`else` for teh win.

Comment: This whole question smells like someone comfortable with functional programming trying to use PHP and not getting why it doesn't work. No offense to anyone, but it's not *just* the OP that's the problem here.

Comment: Well I've begun using OOP a few months ago.. it takes a bit time to get used to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)-without-the-middle-part, available since PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

- First, don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated.
- Second, `mysql_query` returns a resource which you have to fetch from. Having one variable contain either a resource or a string is bad practice.

Here's a better way:

```
$q= 'SELECT a, b, c FROM mytable';
if($r= $db->query($q)){
  $success = 'yep';
  while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do stuff
  }
} else {
  $success = 'nope';
}
```

Comment: I know, thanks, I just started learning about PDO. How in the world have I been able to live when I was using mysql_query, mysql_fecth_object and mysql_num_rows?

Comment: To be fair, having a variable or a function be more than one type is a standard php practice. Not a good one, just a one.

Answer (score 0):

Do not write your code like this. The result from mysql_query will not always be a Boolean value that can be compared. You are also going to lose any error messages and error handling that can be performed when querying the database.

Short answer: Yes. Long Answer: Don't

Comment: I took the mysql_query as an example, it would be any other function

Answer (score 0):

Use the `or` operator, instead of `||`. it has a lower binding preference. e.g.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) || die(mysql_error()); // always kills the script
v.s.
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // kills the script ONLY if the query returns false
```

However, don't use such convoluted code. Reducing line count is a fine thing, but when it makes readability suffer, it's a horribly bad thing.

The main problem is that a `SELECT` query either returns a boolean false (query/db failure), or a result set. You cannot know what the result set is until you actually retrieve a row of data and examin it. e.g. Just because a query call returned a non-false value, doesn't mean the query actually suceeded. A query which returns no data is still a valid query.

e.g. consider a login system, and you're checking if an account exists:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=Some_username_that_doesnt_exist";
$exists = mysql_query($sql) or "Nope!";
```

The query is perfectly valid, but since the username doesn't exist, will return an empty result set. That's a non-false result, so the `or Nope` doesn't trigger. Now the code thinks the username exists, and poof... off you go on an incorrect code path.

Comment: Well, except that php guarantees that the result of a boolean operation is a boolean. So if `mysql_query($sql)` returns a boolean `false` or a result set, `$result = mysql_query($sql) or something_else();` is guaranteed to be false. Capturing the return value of `die()` just doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: Is there a difference between or and ||? That sounds a bit odd

Comment: @Dremp yes. It is odd. The only difference is the precedence.

Comment: @dremp: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php